# How to set Watch Dog Timer in Intel Galileo

Tags: arduino, watchdog, intel-galileo

I am working on Intel Galileo (Linux running on it). Now I want to set a watch dog timer to reset my sketch if some error is acknowledged or my sketch crashes due to some reason.

I have gone through Intel Galileo datasheet but didn't find anything regarding watch dog timer.

So, I tried quark x1000 datasheet but couldn't make much out of it.

I am not able to understand how watch dog timer is initialized on Intel Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

Information on the watchdog timer is in Section 21.14 in [this document](http://download.intel.com/support/processors/quark/sb/quarkdatasheetrev02.pdf).

However, the watchdog timer isn't going to recognize that your sketch crashed, only if the entire OS crashed.

Comment: Is there any way to monitor a particular process status(running properly or crashed).